# "You applied for this position" message doesn't indicate rejection

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Some time ago, I applied for a position on Careers, and received a very nice email turning me down. When I looked at the same position just now, there was a banner across the top saying, "You applied for this position on September 9. Good luck!"

Don't you think it'd be more decent and civilized to have it say, "You applied for this position, but the employer has decided to explore other candidates", or something similar? At least provide the employer with the ability to tag a given application as rejected.

Comment: For me, it is sufficient to say only that I have applied for the position. Anything else is superfluous.