# Should Indicate which Positions I've Already Applied For

Tags: feature-request, jobs

When showing the job-search results, it would be incredibly useful if there was an indication for which of those jobs I've already applied for.

As it stands, I risk thinking I already applied for a position that I didn't, or re-applying for a position, potentially irritating the company.

I know [I can track which positions I've applied for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121678/where-can-i-see-positions-and-companies-i-have-applied-to), but some companies have more than one similarly titled positions, and it isn't always clear if a position is one I've applied for, or just another position within the same company.

Comment: Guess you don't see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242887/you-applied-for-this-position-message-doesnt-indicate-rejection

Comment: @random: The answer to the first question says to click on the messages link, but both the OP and myself are asking for an indication to appear within the job search results. This would be incredibly useful and a great time saver. The second question doesn't appear to have any answer, so I'm not sure what your point was there.

Comment: If you're looking at a job post and it doesn't have that banner, you haven't sent an application for it

Comment: Not a dupe. Voting to reopen. /cc @Lance